# Meaning of 文字起こし?

Tags: grammar, meaning

> 話し合って、らいあんさんにはエンディング、オープニング、エフェクトなどの編集をお願いします！もう1人お願いする方がいて、その人に文字起こしなどお願いすることになりました！

I am working as a video editor for my client and I understand the first sentence, but I am having difficulty understanding the phrase 文字起こし, what does it mean in this context?

Comment: https://jisho.org/search/%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E8%B5%B7%E3%81%93%E3%81%97

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be solved by a single dictionary search.

Answer (score 1):

It means "transcription" (convert speech into a written document.)
It is also called テープ起こし (from the olden days when audio was mainly recorded on tapes). It can be a word-to-word, or involve some editing.